# include all referenced documents in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

Right now I get the desired output by emitting almost everything and then combining the output in my node.js server.

The problem is that since I can't access the group document from the poll document to emit the group's members, so I have to emit every group and their members/created_by.

I would like to know if this even possible or do I need to restructure my documents or what?

Anyway these are the example documents and the desired output.

poll1:

```
{
   "_id": "0166801aff2aca04894bbd42b200003a",
   "doc_type": "poll",
   "question": "What to do?",
   "choices": [
       {
           "_id": "530d40abfb606d0fc12131e3b1b51590",
           "text": "Nothing",
           "votes": [
               "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9"
           ],
           "created_by": "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9"
       },
       {
           "_id": "f01c25231cef239b84a1a25bcbf0eb1b",
           "text": "Everything",
           "votes": [
               "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9",
               "967cb55f3fbb27a25c45b5e7d8cecd4f"
           ],
           "created_by": "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9"
       }
   ],
   "created_by": "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9",
   "expire_date": "1475535772",
   "groups": [
       "d6cdb694358b81ac0bcfa8574d7d6c72"
   ]
}
```

group1:

```
{
   "_id": "d6cdb694358b81ac0bcfa8574d7d6c72",
   "doc_type": "group",
   "name": "Friends",
   "members": [
       "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9"
   ],
   "created_by": "967cb55f3fbb27a25c45b5e7d8cecd4f"
}
```

user1:

```
{
   "_id": "967cb55f3fbb27a25c45b5e7d8cecd4f",
   "doc_type": "user",
   "uuid": "d272c0bc-9f6d-42f9-9503-0e11735f7798",
   "username": "Peter"
}
```

user2:

```
{
   "_id": "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9",
   "doc_type": "user",
   "uuid": "40a818e8-0f11-4832-9a18-erd3d85b88b0",
   "username": "Thomas"
}
```

the desired output:

```
{
    "_id": "0166801aff2aca04894bbd42b200003a",
    "doc_type": "poll",
    "question": "What to do?",
    "choices": [
        {
            "_id": "530d40abfb606d0fc12131e3b1b51590",
            "text": "Nothing",
            "votes": [
                {
                    "_id": "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9",
                    "doc_type": "user",
                    "uuid": "40a818e8-0f11-4832-9a18-erd3d85b88b0",
                    "username": "Thomas"
                }
            ],
            "created_by": {
                "_id": "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9",
                "doc_type": "user",
                "uuid": "40a818e8-0f11-4832-9a18-erd3d85b88b0",
                "username": "Thomas"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "f01c25231cef239b84a1a25bcbf0eb1b",
            "text": "Everything",
            "votes": [
                {
                    "_id": "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9",
                    "doc_type": "user",
                    "uuid": "40a818e8-0f11-4832-9a18-erd3d85b88b0",
                    "username": "Thomas"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "967cb55f3fbb27a25c45b5e7d8cecd4f",
                    "doc_type": "user",
                    "uuid": "d272c0bc-9f6d-42f9-9503-0e11735f7798",
                    "username": "Peter"
                }
            ],
            "created_by": {
                "_id": "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9",
                "doc_type": "user",
                "uuid": "40a818e8-0f11-4832-9a18-erd3d85b88b0",
                "username": "Thomas"
            }
        }
    ],
    "created_by": {
        "_id": "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9",
        "doc_type": "user",
        "uuid": "40a818e8-0f11-4832-9a18-erd3d85b88b0",
        "username": "Thomas"
    },
    "expire_date": "1475535772",
    "groups": [
        {
            "_id": "d6cdb694358b81ac0bcfa8574d7d6c72",
            "doc_type": "group",
            "name": "Friends",
            "members": [
                {
                    "_id": "ef29b82702be83123837aefd001c46e9",
                    "doc_type": "user",
                    "uuid": "40a818e8-0f11-4832-9a18-erd3d85b88b0",
                    "username": "Thomas"
                }
            ],
            "created_by": {
                "_id": "967cb55f3fbb27a25c45b5e7d8cecd4f",
                "doc_type": "user",
                "uuid": "d272c0bc-9f6d-42f9-9503-0e11735f7798",
                "username": "Peter"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surely get the groups from the view using the [linked documentations](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/couchapp/views/joins.html) but you won't be able to get the users. You would need to query another time.

If you want to use a single query, you could stock some other meta informations into your poll document. For example, you could have the groups with their users ids.

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "groupId": "enter_your_group_id_here",
      "usersIds": [
        "user1",
        "user2",
        "user3"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```